# Firebase Realtime Database Security Design

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, iot

More a design question / explore options - I have a Firebase Realtime Database backed project where I have IOT-like devices (ESP32) that periodically measure environmental conditions and stores data in the database, and a flutter app that users use to associate devices with their account, view data and update device settings.

My question is about the best setup for the IOT devices - i currently have them all using a single service account to access the database and insert new readings. I'm concerned this may open up the project to security issues, and that there is no way to restrict security priveledges of a single device.

The other option is to create individual user accounts for every device (each device would have to register themselves with their own unique id). This would then allow every device to be disabled individually and operate through the security rules defined for the database, but lead to a larger number of users in the auth db and more complex iot device code.

Am I missing anything from the above? Has anyone done something similar and can offer some design insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i currently have them all using a single service account to access the database and insert new readings.

You should only use a service account in trusted environments, as they have full unrestricted access to your Firebase project. In all other scenarios, consider regular SDKs such as the [non-privileged Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node) that is great for using on IoT devices.